# how to disable default html-5 tooltip while using bootstrap 4 tooltip

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

i use bootstrap tooltip like this

```
<i class="m-2 far fa-heart like" id="p-like" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Please login"></i>
```

and i active that with this script

```
$('#p-like').tooltip();
```

but tooltip two times display. what is my mistake. thanks for you'r help.

[image]

Comment: Remove the title attribute.

Comment: so how to set message for tooltip?? @RobMoll

Comment: I can't reproduce the error https://jsfiddle.net/cm80u9jk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change title attr to data-title this do like this

```
$('.like').each(function () {
        let title = $(this).attr('data-title');
        $(this).tooltip({title: title, animation: true});
    });
```